# Ошибка в Unity 2D, обращение к нулевому объекту, помогите

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть простенький скрипт кликера, который выдаёт следующую ошибку:

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
NewBehaviourScript.Update () (at Assets/SCRIPTS/NewBehaviourScript.cs:35)

Вот сам скрипт:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] int money;
    public int total_money;
    public Text moneyText;

    private void Start()
    {
        money = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("money");
        total_money = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("total_money");
    }

    public void ButtonClick()
    {
        money++;
        total_money++;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("money", money);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("total_money", total_money);
    }

    public void ToAchievements()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(1);  
    }

    void Update()
    {
        moneyText.text = money.ToString();
    }
}
```

В Юнити, да и в целом программировании я довольно тугой, так что не бейте тапками сильно

Comment: @aepot 35-я строка это предпоследняя фигурная скобка, закрывающая метод void Update()

Comment: Ну тогда видимо `moneyText` у вас `null`.

Comment: @aepot вроде в этом методе значение money, преобразованное в ToString, как раз и присваивается для moneyText

Comment: Ну переменная типа `int` не может быть `null`, значит остается только одно. Обратите внимание, не `moneyText.text` null, а `moneyText`. Вы пытаетесь обратиться к свойству `text` у ничего, поэтому и исключение. Но вы же уже прочитали ответ по ссылке, и уже это знаете, верно?